# Is there a way to see if the angular mock modules are loaded?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following code in my spec file

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module('app');

    inject(function ($injector) {
        user = $injector.get('app.user');
    });
});
```

`user` is undefined, and isn't being injected.  So I want to make sure that the `app` module actually loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If the module is not loaded, you get [`$injector:nomod` error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod). If the module is loaded but the service cannot be found, you get [`$injector:unpr` error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr). It is as easy as that. There is always a breadcrumb trail, no need to probe Angular to know if it fails silently or not.

Comment: What I've noticed is that the injector callback isn't firing.  If I remove the `module()` call, it fires, then I get the error you mentioned.

Comment: Have you got any specs for this beforeEach? I don't think that it is possible for injector callback to not fire and not throw, the problem may be in your Karma setup or anywhere else. And you shouldn't trust console.log when debugging it, you need to now exactly if it fires or not to make a conclusion. console depends on the setup.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's an issue with the karma config.  I'm just trying to narrow down where it's failing, and what's not loading.

Comment: 'app.user' service name looks fishy to me. Shouldn't it be 'user'? Any way, I would jump to specs for debugging. Try something like `it('..', inject(['app.user', (app_user) => { expect(app_user).to... }])))`, you may get all the feedback you need this way without messing with console.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try

Comment: Got it.  The module registration was failing silently. (grrrrr).  There was another module that was pulled in through NPM that was missing from the karma configuration.

Comment: So test run failed before the specs had a chance to start? This makes sense.

Comment: All the tests ran.  The module registration failed silently, which caused the injector not to run.  So all the injected objects were left undefined, so all the tests failed.

Comment: Oh, and I decided to try setting the browser to chrome instead of phantom js. That's where I got a message that the module loading failed.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you're using the right module name. You can use `beforeEach` to load your module. Also, with `$injector` you can get an instance of your service or controller you're trying to test:

```
'use strict';
describe('MyControllerName', function () {

  var MyControllerName;

  beforeEach(module('myAppMomduleName'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    MyControllerName = $injector.get('MyControllerName');
  }));

  it('should create an instance of the controller', function () {
    expect(MyControllerName).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Comment: All the names are definitely correct, but I'm not sure if they're being loaded.  And if I put a console.log() statement inside the callback inside the injector, it never fires.  Something's not right, and at this point I'm trying to figure out where it's not working.

Comment: Any Luck? Having the same issue